# Completely remap keys in Mac OS X

Tags: linux, macos, xorg, macbook-pro, keyboard-layout

I'd like to remap some keys on my Mac OS X 10.7.5. Those mappings are not that trivial, for example I would like that 'W' key behaves as Return and right 'Apple cmd' behaves as Arrow down. Is that possible? I used linux previously and it was possible to map anything via xmodmap program.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many non-alphanumeric keys or key combinations can't be changed from keylayout files or with Ukelele, but you can use [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/). Add something like this to [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en):

```
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::W, KeyCode::RETURN</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_R, KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN</autogen>
```

See the source for the [key code constants](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data) and [predefined settings](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/tree/version_8.0.0/src/core/server/Resources/include/checkbox/).

Comment: do you know, where is the full key code constants list? I need to be able to map czech characters like r with caron and so.

Comment: ř should be just KEY_5. You can add key code values with [symbol_map](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml-keycode.html.en), but most keys should have them already. If your main layout is U.S., there's no way to output ř though. You have to create a custom keylayout (with Ukelele) and change the output of keys.

Answer (score 0):

[Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) works great for this!  Easy and intuitive to use.  Modifies the system mapping of the keyboard so no utility needs to run at boot or anything.

Comment: can you show me some example, how to map non-char keys like 'Return' to something? I tried Ukelele and there was always a need to enter a char

Answer (score 0):

xmodmap can be installed on your mac. I would use MacPorts, since I already have it set up; you might prefer to build from source manually.

Comment: what's the line to install it with macports package manager? and can it be installed with brew package manager?